# Shell navigation bar scroll behavior

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-toolbar, xamarin.forms.shell

I would like to ask if it is possible to animate the Navigation Bar or `TabbedPage` (`TabLayout`) in the Xamarin.Forms `Shell` when scrolling it either hides or the discovery see gif. I tried it in Xamarin native android there it works after adding `layout_scrollFlags`.

http://lomza.totem-soft.com/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout_scrollflags

http://karthikraj.net/2016/12/24/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can achieve this behavior with an android style in XF + Shell, but you can achieve it using a custom renderer by overriding `CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()`.

```
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            base.CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker();
            return new MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
        }
    }
```

**MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker** (name it whatever you want)

```
using LP = Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
...
public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
{
        public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
        {
        }

        public override void SetAppearance(AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);
            toolbar.LayoutParameters = new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(LP.MatchParent, LP.WrapContent)
            {
                ScrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.ScrollFlagScroll |
                AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.ScrollFlagEnterAlways
            };
        }
}
```

Don't forget to properly decorate it with `ExportRenderer` as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers).

---

(ignore this section if the below linked bug/issue is closed)

#### Known Side-Effect

This is a trivial undesired side-effect caused by a [Xamarin.Forms Bug 13338](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13338)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought so.