# Shell navigation bottom and upper TabBar scroll behavior

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-toolbar, xamarin.forms.shell

In follow-up of [Shell navigation bar scroll behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544512/shell-navigation-bar-scroll-behavior), I have created a custom Shell renderer toolbar with scroll behavior and I would like to know if it is possible to create the same for TabBar or Tab in Shell. See Gif

https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e

[image]

```
 using LP = Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
 public class CustomShell : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShell(Context context) : base(context) { }
    protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        base.CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker();
        return new MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
    }
}

public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
{
    public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
    {
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);

        toolbar.LayoutParameters = new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(LP.MatchParent, LP.WrapContent)
        {
            ScrollFlags = AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.ScrollFlagScroll |
                          AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.ScrollFlagEnterAlways,
        };
    }
}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
 <FlyoutItem Title="Home" 
        FlyoutIcon="{StaticResource FontIconHome}"
        FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsSingleItem">
<Tab Title="Home"
     Icon="{StaticResource FontIconHome}">
       <ShellContent Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate homepage:HomePage}" />
</Tab>
<Tab Title="Download"
     Icon="{StaticResource FontIconDownLoad}">
    <ShellContent Route="DownloadPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate downloadpage:DownloadPage}" />
</Tab>
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve the effect of the above picture？

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to achieve the same effect as in the picture above.  I need the bottom control panel to scroll just like the top ToolBar.  I tried to create my own render and edit CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker but I didn't do very well.

Comment: Maybe you need to get BottomNavigationView  by shell custom render, override **CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker method**, then writing a custom CoordinatorLayout Behavior for BottomNavigationView .